# Probability density function where random variable follows binomial distribution and probability varies

Tags: r

I have a variable that follows binomial distribution
X~Bin(p,15) and the observed outcome is 3.

Now I would want to plot a density function with all the different possible values of p (from 0 to 1). In other words I want to plot the density function that shows the possibility to observe the outcome 3 when p is 0,...0.5...1 and so on.

How could I do this?

Comment: I think that X axis is the success rate of Bernoulli `p`. But I cannot understand what do you mean the Y axis?

Comment: I agree with @CamfordOxbridge that your question could be more clear. Are you looking for something like `p <- seq(0, 1, 0.01); f <- dbinom(3, 15, p); plot(p, f, type = "l", ylab = "f(p)")`?

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Where exactly did you get stuck? Please show your code you have so far in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
likelihood <- function(p) (
  return(dbinom(3, size = 15, prob = p))
)

curve(likelihood)
```